# How to execute 'netsh' command through subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, python-2.7, netsh

I am running a batch file which in turn runs a python file. I want to execute netsh command to change the IPv4 settings from static to dhcp and vice versa.

When I run the below code it executes and returns without any error

```
import subprocess
cmd = "netsh interface ip show config"
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print output
```

But when I execute the this piece of code through a batch file the python file exits with exit status 1.

```
import subprocess
cmd = '''netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection 9" dhcp'''
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print output
```

And It throws an error

> Python: can't open file 'Update_DHCP.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The python file and the batch file are in same folder and as per my understanding of updating the dhcp Ip, requires admin rights. I am even running the .bat file as 'Run as Administrator' but got the error [Errno 2]

I have also tried to create a task using task scheduler to grant admin rights to the .bat file and run it. But still, it din't work for me.

Can any one help me execute the command using subprocess.check_output() as I want to use the output returned by the check_output() call. Any help would be appreciated.

I am working on Windows and my python version is 2.7

Comment: What does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: Removed irrelevant tags.

Comment: @JamesC. Well yeah, I could have done that. I wanted to give the OP a chance to clarify. Guess we can rollback the edit if they really do want a powershell answer.

Comment: Could you also show us the directory structure/contents of the bash file?